# element-ui el-select weird behavior

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I got weird behavior when using el-select

[image]

el-option show in horizontal selection, I've tried remove all css but it still not work as normal option selection. My code is straightforward and doesn't have another setting

```
  <el-select size="mini" v-model="form.status" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option label="All Status" value=""></el-option>
    <el-option
      v-for="item in optionsStatus"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
```

do you have this kind of experience to solve this?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the relevant elements. Somewhere there must be CSS to make this happen. If there's nothing obvious then try comparing it with an official demo to see what the difference is.

Comment: I've tried remove css but it doesn't work..
there is some kind of data-v-xxxx in rendered browser. it works normal if I delete it but it added automatic based on data

Comment: The `data-v-xxxx` suggests you have some scoped CSS in that component. Make sure you refresh the page after deleting it. If it's still hanging around then use the developer tools to identify exactly what the CSS is so you can search for it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. When I inspected the CSS of <el-select>, I found it containing some <li> children and I tried adjusting the CSS attributes to find what cause this. Finally I found the bug: When I remove "display: inline-block;" the <el-select> options displaying vertically in normal. Then I went back my code and found <li> has "display: inline-block;" which was copied from HelloWorld.vue created by default Vue project. Hope it can help.